# Referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am getting the following error when calling `context.Set<Person>().Attach(person);` on EF 5.0

> *A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.*

Is there some way to figure out which exact property is generating this error?

I know what the cause is, that a foreign key which is directly a property of an object is different from the related object's primary key, so for example:

```
Person --> Address
ID         PersonID
           Person
```

and `Address.PersonID` isn't the same as `Address.Person.PersonID`, but no matter where I look at my real life object I am not getting which property is causing this.

So is there some way to get to the root of the problem, maybe stepping through the ObjectStateManager or some ChangeTracking routine?

I have already written a t4 template file (to autogenerate it based on my entitymodel) that checks every ForeignKey/PrimaryKey, and I just cannot find a difference.

Comment: You know it's the data, not the schema, that is causing the error...right?  If an Address record has a PersonID of 100, and there is no Person with a PersonID of 100...that will cause the error.

Comment: Please can you paste in your Person class and person object prior to attaching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi ForeignKey ruined my day...

So to complete my sample above it was like;

```
Person --> Address
ID         PersonID
ID2        PersonID2
           Person
```

And I didnt check the ID2 of my objects, which was loaded incorrectly.